# Conway's Game of Life in a C# class. Is this sensibly factored and well tested?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, game-of-life

I'm learning C# and have written the below class to encapsulate the game state of Conway's Game of Life and its update methods.  I'm also learning about implementing light automated unit tests for this project from the beginning.  My overall goal is to build an Android app implementation of the game (using Xamarin) where this class is a component.

```
// This code is intended to be a component in an Android app implementation of Conway's Game of Life,
// built with C# and Xamarin.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConwayStateExplorer
{
    // This exception type is used within the ConwayStateVector class to indicate either that live cells have reached
    // the boundary of game space during a state update, or that a caller has passed invalid coordinates to
    // ConwayStateVector.CellState or ConwayStateVector.NextCellStateUpdate.
    public class GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException : Exception
    {
        public GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException()
        {
        }

        public GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }
    }

    // This class encapsulates the game state and the methods used to update it.
    public class ConwayStateVector
    {
        // The game state is held as an byte[,] in _currentState, where 1 represents a live cell and 0 a dead cell.
        // _stateSnapshot is used by UpdateState to store a version of the game state that stays constant during a
        // game state update computation.  Callers interact with CurrentIndex, CellState and NextCellStateUpdate using
        // array centred origin coordinates (variables prefixed with centre) while the game state is handled internally
        // using 0 based array coordinates (variables prefixed with array).  The CentreToArrayCoordinates and
        // ArrayToCentreCoordinates methods are used to convert between these two coordinate systems.
        private byte[,] _currentState, _stateSnapshot;
        private (int i, int j) _currentIndex, _centreCell, _centreMin, _centreMax;
        public readonly int ArrayLimitI, ArrayLimitJ;
        public readonly (int i, int j) CentreMinLimit, CentreMaxLimit;

        public ConwayStateVector(int sizeI, int sizeJ)
        {
            _currentState = new byte[sizeI, sizeJ];
            _stateSnapshot = new byte[sizeI, sizeJ];
            ArrayLimitI = sizeI - 1;
            ArrayLimitJ = sizeJ - 1;
            _centreCell.i = sizeI / 2 - 1;
            _centreCell.j = sizeJ / 2 - 1;
            CentreMinLimit = ArrayToCentreCoordinates(0, 0);
            CentreMaxLimit = ArrayToCentreCoordinates(ArrayLimitI, ArrayLimitJ);
        }

        // The CurrentIndex property is used to set the index in _currentState that will be read the next time
        // the CellState property is called.
        public (int centreI, int centreJ) CurrentIndex
        {
            set
            {
                (int, int) newArrayIndex;

                if (value.centreI < CentreMinLimit.i || value.centreI > CentreMaxLimit.i
                    || value.centreJ < CentreMinLimit.j || value.centreJ > CentreMaxLimit.j)
                {
                    throw new GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException
                              ("CurrentIndex: Attempt to set next game state read index outside bounds of game space.");
                }

                newArrayIndex = CentreToArrayCoordinates(value.centreI, value.centreJ);
                _currentIndex = newArrayIndex;
            }
        }

        public int CellState
        {
            get { return _currentState[_currentIndex.i, _currentIndex.j]; }
        }

        // This property is used to flip the state of a specified index in _currentState from 0 to 1 or vice versa.
        public (int centreI, int centreJ) NextCellStateUpdate
        {
            set
            {
                (int i, int j) arrayIndex;

                if (value.centreI < CentreMinLimit.i || value.centreI > CentreMaxLimit.i
                    || value.centreJ < CentreMinLimit.j || value.centreJ > CentreMaxLimit.j)
                {
                    throw new GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException
                              ("SetCellState: Attempt to set cell state outside bounds of game space.");
                }

                arrayIndex = CentreToArrayCoordinates(value.centreI, value.centreJ);

                if (_currentState[arrayIndex.i, arrayIndex.j] == 0)
                {
                    _currentState[arrayIndex.i, arrayIndex.j] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    _currentState[arrayIndex.i, arrayIndex.j] = 0;
                }

                if (value.centreI - 1 < _centreMin.i) { _centreMin.i = value.centreI - 1; }

                if (value.centreI + 1 > _centreMax.i) { _centreMax.i = value.centreI + 1; }

                if (value.centreJ - 1 < _centreMin.j) { _centreMin.j = value.centreJ - 1; }

                if (value.centreJ + 1 > _centreMax.j) { _centreMax.j = value.centreJ + 1; }
            }
        }

        // These two methods are used to transform from centre to array coordinates and vice versa, respectively.
        private (int, int) CentreToArrayCoordinates(int i, int j)
        {
            return (_centreCell.i + i, _centreCell.j + j);
        }

        private (int, int) ArrayToCentreCoordinates(int i, int j)
        {
            return (i - _centreCell.i, j - _centreCell.j);
        }

        // This method is used to update the game state at each game logic tick according to the rules of the game.
        public void UpdateState()
        {
            int i, j;
            (int i, int j) arrayMin, arrayMax, newCentreMin = (0, 0), newCentreMax = (0, 0), centrePos;
            int baseValue, posIZeroJValue, posINegJValue, zeroINegJValue, negINegJValue, negIZeroJValue, negIPosJValue;
            int zeroIPosJValue, posIPosJValue, localPopulation;
            bool lifeFlag;

            if (_centreMin.i <= CentreMinLimit.i || _centreMax.i >= CentreMaxLimit.i || _centreMin.j <= CentreMinLimit.j
                || _centreMax.j >= CentreMaxLimit.j)
            {
                throw new GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException("UpdateState: The boundary of game space has been reached.");
            }

            arrayMin = CentreToArrayCoordinates(_centreMin.i, _centreMin.j);
            arrayMax = CentreToArrayCoordinates(_centreMax.i, _centreMax.j);
            Array.Copy(_currentState, 0, _stateSnapshot, 0, (ArrayLimitI + 1) * (ArrayLimitJ + 1));

            for (i = arrayMin.i; i <= arrayMax.i; i++)
            {
                for (j = arrayMin.j; j <= arrayMax.j; j++)
                {
                    centrePos = ArrayToCentreCoordinates(i, j);
                    baseValue = _stateSnapshot[i, j];
                    posIZeroJValue = _stateSnapshot[i + 1, j];
                    posINegJValue = _stateSnapshot[i + 1, j - 1];
                    zeroINegJValue = _stateSnapshot[i, j - 1];
                    negINegJValue = _stateSnapshot[i - 1, j - 1];
                    negIZeroJValue = _stateSnapshot[i - 1, j];
                    negIPosJValue = _stateSnapshot[i - 1, j + 1];
                    zeroIPosJValue = _stateSnapshot[i, j + 1];
                    posIPosJValue = _stateSnapshot[i + 1, j + 1];
                    localPopulation = posIZeroJValue + posINegJValue + zeroINegJValue + negINegJValue
                    + negIZeroJValue + negIPosJValue + zeroIPosJValue + posIPosJValue;

                    if (baseValue == 1)
                    {
                        if (localPopulation == 2 || localPopulation == 3)
                        {
                            lifeFlag = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _currentState[i, j] = 0;
                            lifeFlag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (localPopulation == 3)
                        {
                            _currentState[i, j] = 1;
                            lifeFlag = true;
                        }
                        else { lifeFlag = false; }
                    }

                    if (lifeFlag == true)
                    {
                        if (centrePos.i < newCentreMin.i) { newCentreMin.i = centrePos.i; }
                        else if (centrePos.i > newCentreMax.i) { newCentreMax.i = centrePos.i; }
                        else if (centrePos.j < newCentreMin.j) { newCentreMin.j = centrePos.j; }
                        else if (centrePos.j > newCentreMax.j) { newCentreMax.j = centrePos.j; }
                    }
                }
            }

            _centreMin = newCentreMin;
            _centreMax = newCentreMax;
        }

        // This method is intended to allow the unit tests to access _currentState.
        public byte[,] TestState()
        {
            return _currentState;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string command, position, runStatus = "run", stateText;
            string[] components;
            int componentI, componentJ;
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            byte[,] initialState1 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter command: ");
                command = Console.ReadLine();

                if (command == "set")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter position: ");
                    position = Console.ReadLine();
                    components = position.Split(',');
                    componentI = Convert.ToInt32(components[0]);
                    componentJ = Convert.ToInt32(components[1]);
                    gameState.NextCellStateUpdate = (componentI, componentJ);
                    stateText = ShowState(gameState);
                    Console.WriteLine(stateText);
                }
                else if (command == "u")
                {
                    gameState.UpdateState();
                    stateText = ShowState(gameState);
                    Console.WriteLine(stateText);
                }
                else { runStatus = "Stop"; }

            } while (runStatus == "run");

        }

        // This function transforms the game state to a text representation so this can be output in the console.
        static string ShowState(ConwayStateVector gameState)
        {
            int i, j, state;
            string outputString = "";

            for (i = -3; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                for (j = -3; j <= 4; j++)
                {
                    gameState.CurrentIndex = (i, j);
                    state = gameState.CellState;
                    outputString = outputString + Convert.ToString(state) + " ";
                }

                outputString = outputString + "\n";
            }

            return outputString;
        }

        
    }
}
```

These are the test methods.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Linq;
using ConwayStateExplorer;

namespace ConwayStateTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class StateUpdateTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test whether ConwayStateVector.UpdateState correctly updates the game state when
        // given a set of example states.
        public void UpdateState_CorrectStateUpdate()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState;
            byte[,] nextState;

            // This tests live cells with 0 live neighbours and dead cells with 0 or 1 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState1 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            // This tests live cells with 1 live neighbour and dead cells with 0, 1 or 2 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState2 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            // This tests live cells with 1 or 2 live neighbours and dead cells with 0, 1, 2 or 3 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState3 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            // This tests live cells with 3 live neighbours and dead cells with 0, 1 or 2 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState4 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            // This tests live cells with 2, 3 or 4 live neighbours and dead cells with 0, 1, 2 or 3 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState5 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            // This tests live cells with 2 or 4 live neighbours and dead cells with 0, 1, 2, 3 or 8 live neighbours.
            byte[,] initialState6 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState1 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState2 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState3 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState4 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState5 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            byte[,] predictedState6 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState1);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState1, nextState), "UpdateState test 1 failed.");
            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState2);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState2, nextState), "UpdateState test 2 failed.");
            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState3);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState3, nextState), "UpdateState test 3 failed.");
            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState4);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState4, nextState), "UpdateState test 4 failed.");
            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState5);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState5, nextState), "UpdateState test 5 failed.");
            gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState6);
            gameState.UpdateState();
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState6, nextState), "UpdateState test 6 failed.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.UpdateState correctly detects that the boundary of
        // game space has been reached and throws the appropriate exception.
        public void UpdateState_InvalidStateUpdate()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            byte[,] initialState1 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState1);
            Assert.ThrowsException<GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException>(() => gameState.UpdateState());
            
        }

        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.NextCellStateUpdate correctly updates the game state,
        // with 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 cell flips tested.
        public void NextCellStateUpdate_ValidUpdate()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            byte[,] nextState;
            byte[,] predictedState1 = {  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
            byte[,] predictedState2 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            gameState.NextCellStateUpdate = (1, 2);
            nextState = gameState.TestState();
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState1, nextState), "NextCellStateUpdate test 1 failed.");
            gameState.NextCellStateUpdate = (1, 2);
            Assert.IsTrue(CompareStates(predictedState2, nextState), "NextCellStateUpdate test 2 failed.");

        }

        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.NextCellStateUpdate correctly detects that the centred
        // origin coordinates passed are outside of game space and throws the appropriate exception.
        public void NextCellStateUpdate_InvalidUpdate()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            Assert.ThrowsException<GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException>(() => gameState.NextCellStateUpdate = (-4, 3));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.CurrentIndex and ConwayStateVector.CellState correctly
        // read the game state.
        public void CurrentIndexPlusCellState_ValidIndex()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            byte[,] initialState = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

            SetInitialState(gameState, initialState);
            gameState.CurrentIndex = (1, 0);
            Assert.IsTrue(gameState.CellState == 1, "CurrentIndexPlusCellState test 1 failed.");
            gameState.CurrentIndex = (3, -1);
            Assert.IsTrue(gameState.CellState == 0, "CurrentIndexPlusCellState test 2 failed.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        // This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.CurrentIndex correctly detects that the centred origin
        // coordinates passed are outside of game space and throws the appropriate exception.
        public void CurrentIndexPlusCellState_InvalidIndex()
        {
            ConwayStateVector gameState = new ConwayStateVector(8, 8);
            Assert.ThrowsException<GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException>(() => gameState.CurrentIndex = (2, 5));
        }

        // This method compares the predicted next state of the ConwayStateVector object with its actual state
        // to check if the game logic has worked correctly.
        private bool CompareStates(byte[,] predictedState, byte[,] actualState)
        {
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    if (predictedState[i, j] == actualState[i, j]) { }
                    else { return false; }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        // This method is used to automate the testing of ConwayStateVector.UpdateState by setting the initial state of
        // gameState based on one of the initialState patterns.
        private void SetInitialState(ConwayStateVector gameState, byte[,] newState)
        {
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    if (newState[i, j] == 1) { gameState.NextCellStateUpdate = (i - 3, j - 3); }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Could anyone provide feedback on the use of language features, if you think this is factored sensibly and / or the test methods?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've implemented the "game of life" as an actual game where you have to enter coordinates. That's really weird to me; it's a zero-player game - the living cells play the game.

I've got no clue when I started to read into the code why there are two coordinate systems and two naming conventions. To me this just confuses matters.

### GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException

```
public class GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException : Exception
```

It seems to me that you describe that the exception is used for two different purposes. That's not a good idea, even if it shortens code.  However, you can shorten the exception by only haven an `XxxException(String)` method as you don't use it within a `catch` and always provide a message.

### ConwayStateVector

**Fields**

```
private (int i, int j) _currentIndex, _centreCell, _centreMin, _centreMax;
```

Coordinates are almost always displayed using `x` and `y`. `i` and `j` are almost always used for indexing instead. So if you ever want to have a for / next loop for anything other than the coordinates, you'll run into name clashes; not a good idea. I'd use `Width` and `Height` for the sizes and `x` and `y` for the individual coordinates though.

Only `_centreCell` is currently  initialized, and that means that other coordinates are in a `null` / invalid state.

```
private byte[,] _currentState, _stateSnapshot;
```

If you store a state, you'd store it in a `State` specific class. This class doesn't hold one state, it stores two. Even worse, it keeps track of a current position, which is something that doesn't need to be exposed. It would e.g. preclude a solution that uses multiple threads to create the next state. **Always** keep state to the minimal amount required.

Instead of using `_` prefixes, it is common to simply keep the normal name without `_`; if you must you can use `this.<fieldname>` if confusion arises. It is not actively harmful to use underscores for internal fields; however if you do so then all internal fields should start with a hash, not just a few.

```
public readonly int ArrayLimitI, ArrayLimitJ;
```

First of all, it is much easier to just create a getter and return the size of the arrays. Furthermore, you now make an implementation detail of your class visible: that you use arrays. That's generally not done, as it means you cannot rewrite it to use other constructions later.

I'd be more comfortable with names like `BoardWidth` and `BoardHeight`, for instance. Games are played on a board (the board is the "game space", so actually you've hinted at this yourself). Storing them as `Max` and `Min` doesn't work either: the only time you use them is when you actually need to increase their size by 1 again.

**ConwayStateVector**

```
public ConwayStateVector(int sizeI, int sizeJ)
```

To me a good start would be a board with any width, and where each array has the same "height".

**CurrentIndex**

```
public (int centreI, int centreJ) CurrentIndex
```

This is possibly a current *position* indicated by *two coordinates*. An index is not generally thought of as having two values. Even if you would keep to using the word index then `i` and `j` would be *two indices* just like you have *two coordinates*; they'd probably still together would indicate one position (or possibly one location) though.

Later in the main method you have `Console.WriteLine("\nEnter position: ")`. That should have provided a hint. I see a lot of people trying to be too smart when it comes to naming variables. There is a board. There is a position on a board consisting of two coordinates. That's it.

```
(int, int) newArrayIndex;
```

You don't need a local variable here, you can directly assign to the field.

**UpdateState**

This method is *much* to complex. The number of variables is a very clear indication of it. Some purists would just use up to 7 lines, but that's going a bit too deep. Having 18 local variables to keep track of is however a very clear indication that you've put too much in a single method.

In languages such as C# you only declare variables just before you assign a value to them. That will at least limit the scope of the variables *especially* for the reader.

```
if (_centreMin.i <= CentreMinLimit.i || _centreMax.i >= CentreMaxLimit.i || _centreMin.j <= CentreMinLimit.j
    || _centreMax.j >= CentreMaxLimit.j)
{
    throw new GameStateUpdateOutOfBoundsException("UpdateState: The boundary of game space has been reached.");
}
```

I see many of these tests. If you just loop over `y` and loop over `x` within the `y` loop then you'd only have to check if one of the neighboring cells exist, e.g. `if (exists(position) && isalive(position)) then neighboringCellCount++`. See, no exceptions necessary (and if you program this badly then you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` anyway.

```
posIZeroJValue = _stateSnapshot[i + 1, j];
```

Have you watched "Ender's game"? You start by defining directions. What about `n`, `ne`, `e`, `se`, `s`, `sw`, `w` and `nw`? A lot shorter than these descriptions, right? Although it is questionable if you need those if you just loop over `y` and `x` for getting the neighbors.

You could also create a readonly tuple I suppose `private readonly (int, int) NORTH = (0, -1)`, for instance. Generally we use `x=0, y=0` to be the northwest, and then travel east by increasing `x` and south by increasing `y`) as most computer screens are created that way.

### Program

**Main**

```
            byte[,] initialState1 = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Alright, but what about using resources here instead of literals? And why is the game state never set to this `initialState1`?

```
components = position.Split(',');
componentI = Convert.ToInt32(components[0]);
componentJ = Convert.ToInt32(components[1])
```

Although you should not need internal exceptions when required, you should definitely sanitize your input. You should for instance test if the string consists of two numbers separated by a comma (and maybe whitespace) and check if the `x` and `y` are in the right position.

```
else { runStatus = "Stop"; }
```

Any type error and you stop? That's rude. Just create a `stop` command please.

```
for (i = -3; i <= 4; i++)
{
    for (j = -3; j <= 4; j++)
```

All that work for creating max and min values, and now you just use literals.

### StateUpdateTests

**UpdateState_CorrectStateUpdate**

Why not keep the tests with their initial state and predicated state separate from each other? You're again trying too much at once. Furthermore, if you are doing the counting instead of the computer, usually something is amiss.

**CurrentIndexPlusCellState_ValidIndex**

```
// This method is used to test if ConwayStateVector.CurrentIndex and ConwayStateVector.CellState correctly
// read the game state.

gameState.CurrentIndex = (1, 0);
Assert.IsTrue(gameState.CellState == 1, "CurrentIndexPlusCellState test 1 failed.");
gameState.CurrentIndex = (3, -1);
Assert.IsTrue(gameState.CellState == 0, "CurrentIndexPlusCellState test 2 failed.");
```

At this point you've completely lost me. I presume that `3, -1` is an invalid cell state? Why would it be `0` in that case? Isn't `0` mean that it is dead?

At this point, I may need training; which is weird because I'm pretty sure I've known about the game of life for about 30 years.

Comment: OK, thanks for your detailed feedback.  To answer your first implied question about why the user can set the game state with the console, in any implementation the player (in the 0 player game) needs to be able to set the initial state.  This class is intended to be a component in a larger implementation of the game, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Alright. Do you have any specific goals set for this implementation? The game of life is well known because of its elegance - just a few rules create this huge complexity, much like e.g. Mandelbrot does for fractal geometry. To be honest, the code doesn't currently reflect that but maybe that's because I might not know the goals. I do like that the game itself seems decoupled from any GUI elements though; that's a very common mistake.

Comment: The core of the app is intended to present the user with a view of the board and the choice to set an initial state by screen tapping the initial live cells, or choosing from some preset patterns.

Comment: The app is intended to present the user with a scaleable view of the board, where they can set an initial state by tapping the initial live cells and then run the game.  As for the two coordinate systems the board used in the app will be larger (up to 2048 * 2048) and for efficiency I wanted to avoid applying the game logic to every cell on every tick.  The application area is limited to a rectangle that dynamically grows away from the centre of the board, or shrinks towards it as necessary.  Having two coordinate systems seems to make some of the code to implement that scaling logic simpler.

Comment: OK, having the possibility to expand into the negative values of an axis is a great design. But even then I would stick to this one centered coordinate system and hide anything below it from the user.